# jquery focus on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

How to set the focus on a html element ?

I use `document.getElementById('ID_HTML_wanted').focus();` but my html element "ID_HTML_wanted" as not the focus. I user jquery api [.focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: Stupid, i have omit to set focus when DOM is ready :

    $( document ).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById('ID_HTML_wanted').focus();
    });

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to wrap your code to this code so it executes AFTER DOM is ready

```
$(function(){
    //your code
});
```

so it will become

```
$(function(){
    document.getElementById('ID_HTML_wanted').focus();
});
```

However, your element't don't have .focus() method, if you want to REALLY use jQuery's one, use

```
$(function(){
    $("#ID_HTML_wanted").focus();
});
```

Comment: Yes, i'm stupid, i have omit to set focus when DOM is ready :
`$( document ).ready(function() { $("#ID_HTML_wanted").focus(); });`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, i have effectively omit to set focus when DOM is ready :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#ID_HTML_wanted").focus();
});
```

All three of the following syntaxes of [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) are equivalent:

```
$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
$(handler)
```