# HTML / Javascript - Autofocus to input when user starts typing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a search input on my website with a placeholder "What Are You Looking For...?

When a user lands on my website, I want them to be able to see the placeholder text. When I use HTML5's autofocus attribute, the user lands on the page but does not see the placeholder text.

What I would like to accomplish is the user lands on the page, and the input form is unselected. When the user just starts typing, it will automatically select the input form. What I am trying to avoid is having the user reach for his/her mouse and select the form first.

I really did not know how to word this question in Google, so I apologize if it seems like I am not doing anything to solve this myself. But if anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate all the help.

Comment: So you want the user to just start typing without the cursor being in the search box, and the text appears in that box?

Comment: It's called "focus" just search for setting field focus on body load. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814361/jquery-focus-on-load

Comment: Added a short fiddle to show `.focus()`: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/UPmK9/

Comment: Consider that if some other element receive focus you will not have the reaction "get focus when start typing". (press tab and start typing on that page to check what I mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have the answer in your question... *'When the user just starts typing, it will automatically select the input form.'*

- Bind a onkeyup,
- read the character,
- focus the input,
- put the character as value,
- unbind your event to recover normal behaviour.

:)