# focus on search when page loads

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, focus, onfocus, autofocus

I am trying to set the search on my website as the default focus point on page load.  The search I am using is "search & filter"

I have tried using autofocus and onfocus but cannot get the cursor to show in the search box.  My search is in a widget on my woocommerce shop page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery focus on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814361/jquery-focus-on-load)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery, you can use the [jQuery focus function](https://api.jquery.com/focus/).

If the focus is not been set on page load, it's likely something else is stealing focus.

```js
function setSearchFocus(){
  console.log('setting search focus');
  $( "#search" ).focus();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  setSearchFocus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  Search: <input type="text" name="search" id="search"><br/>
</form>
<br/>
<br/>
<button onClick="setSearchFocus()">Click to set focus</button>
```